# Custom drawRect uses so much memory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a UIView subclass to use it as a rectangle view. And drawRect is overridden as follows :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat radius = 2;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + radius);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI, M_PI / 2, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - radius, radius, M_PI / 2, 0.0f, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + radius);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width - radius, rect.origin.y + radius, radius, 0.0f, -M_PI / 2, 1);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.origin.x + radius, rect.origin.y + radius, radius, -M_PI / 2, M_PI, 1);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

But it uses lots of memory. For example, I can see 10 MB MyRectangleView(CALayer) for every custom rectangle view in VM Tracker (on iPad 4 screen sized rectangle). It's not just this object, every drawRect I implemented leaks and sits on memory, even if I remove and release them.

What causes it? Is there something wrong about my drawRect implementation?

Comment: Are you getting this value from simulator or real device ?

Comment: You are filling and stroking a rounded rect? (Sorry if I'm wrong, there is a lot of `rect.something.something` in there). Why not use layer properties like `cornerRadius`, `borderColor` and `borderWidth` to create the same effect?

Comment: From the simulator, I've tried just shoving this into a blank project, and its not showing any notable increase in memory (couple of kB maybe). From what I remember of using Core Graphics for custom drawing, the usual cause of leaking memory like that is down to a graphics context being copied somewhere - so there's probably more to this than just the code snippet above. Can you paste in any more of the problem code?

Comment: This happens on device. I don't use cornerRadius and borderColor etc. since they cause performance problems in UITableView.
Now I tried on a simple singleview project. And I can see 11 MB of increase in memory. Isn't it too much for a single-colored rectangle?